# Average Interval based on boundaries given by other vectors - "R"

Tags: r, excel, concatenation

Allow me to give an Excel example.

Imagine the following data as Excel columns:

`A1=5 | A2=3 |  A3=7  | A4=11 |  A5=23 |  A6=15  | A7=17`    then   `B1=1 | B2=4`    also     `C1=3 | C2=7`

I would like to create a column "D" that calculates an average of column "A" with criteria based on columns B and C. So, in this example `D1=(Average of A1 to A3)` based on `B1=1` and `C1=3`... then `D2=(Average of A4 to A7)`, based on `B2=4` and `C2=7`.

The way this can be done on Excel is `D1 = AVERAGE(INDIRECT(CONCATENATE("A",B1)):INDIRECT(CONCATENATE("A",C1)))` and of course `D2 = AVERAGE(INDIRECT(CONCATENATE("A",B2)):INDIRECT(CONCATENATE("A",C2)))`

So D1 concatenation will fuse "A" with "1" because `B1=1` and fuse "A" with "3" because `C1=3`
same with D2 ...... `Average(A4:A7)`

This seems impossible with R because I can't see how you can fuse a number with a column to locate a specific cell and then feed it to the mean function to average a specific range.

I think answering this one will provide many tools that go well beyond this problem.

**Edit:**

Thank you Chi Pak

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A `vector` of values, like in column `A`:

```
set.seed(1)
A <- sample(1:100,10)

[1] 66 13 27 38  2 37 82 32 45 55
```

A `data.frame` of values, like in columns `B` and `C`:

```
df <- data.frame( B = c(1,4), C = c(3,7))

  B C
1 1 3
2 4 7
```

This has 2 rows and 2 columns with column names `B` and `C`.

To calculate the average in column `A` by rows specified by columns `B` and `C`, use `sapply`, which the `R` equivalent of a fast `for` loop. I use `iter` from the library `iterators` to loop through rows of the `data.frame`:

```
install.packages("iterators")
library(iterators)
sapply(iter(df,by="row"),function(x) mean(A[x$B:x$C]))

[1] 35.33333 39.75000
```